# Consistency of SDK tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a number of tags for the various Stellar SDKs available.  At present:
[stellar-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-sdk)
[java-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-sdk)
[go-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-sdk)
[stellar-dotnet-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-dotnet-sdk)
[javascriptsdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascriptsdk)

I suggest that there should be more consistency in the naming - especially as other SDKs will presumably get their own tags in future.

In particular:
[stellar-dotnet-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-dotnet-sdk) should be [dotnet-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-sdk) as "Stellar" is superfluous.
[javascriptsdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascriptsdk) should be [javascript-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript-sdk) to retain the convention of using a hyphen as a separator.

Should we rename these tags while there aren't too many question using them yet?  Alternatively create synonyms which point to tags which have a common format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest `$language-sdk` where language should lean towards its full form to avoid ambiguity. E.g. [javascript-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript-sdk) instead of [js-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/js-sdk). Although [go-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-sdk) is probably better than [golang-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang-sdk).

Questions marked [stellar-sdk](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-sdk) should be retagged with the specific SDK where appropriate or [api](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) if it refers specifically the Horizon API. On that note, I think  [api](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) should be [horizon-api](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizon-api).

Comment: I agree with this.  Now that we've gone a week without any dissenting voice, I propose we go ahead with this.

Comment: I've reviewed all sdk/api tagged questions. ✓